# String equality vs equality of location

Tags: java, string, equality

```
String s1 = "BloodParrot is the man";  
String s2 = "BloodParrot is the man";  
String s3 = new String("BloodParrot is the man");  

System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
System.out.println(s1 == s2);
System.out.println(s1 == s3);
System.out.println(s1.equals(s3));
```

// output
true
true
false
true

Why don't all the strings have the same location in memory if all three have the same contents?

Comment: Is this Java or C#. The answer to your question seems to depend on the language. You may wish to tag it accordingly.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate.  This question is more about interning strings than it is about comparing them.

Comment: I guess that last comment makes no sense unless I mention that I rolled back an edit saying that this question was a duplicate of another.  Feel free to add the link back in and vote to close if you disagree.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java only automatically interns String *literals*.  New String objects (created using the `new` keyword) are not interned by default.  You can use the [String.intern()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) method to intern an existing String object. Calling `intern` will check the existing String pool for a matching object and return it if one exists or add it if there was no match.

If you add the line

```
s3 = s3.intern();
```

to your code right after you create `s3`, you'll see the difference in your output.

[See some more examples and a more detailed explanation](http://javatechniques.com/blog/string-equality-and-interning/).

This of course brings up the very important topic of when to use == and when to use the `equals` method in Java.  You almost always want to use `equals` when dealing with object references.  The == operator compares reference values, which is *almost* never what you mean to compare.  Knowing the difference helps you decide when it's appropriate to use == or `equals`.

Answer (score 3):

You explicitly call new for s3 and this leaves you with a new instance of the string.

Comment: Oh, so the only difference is the use of the "new" keyword. So the strings that don't use the new keyword are not instances of a string object?

Comment: They are instances, but they may not necessarily have dedicated buffers.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a `String` is actually a fast process. Trying to find any previously created `String` will be much slower.

Consider what you need to do to make all `String`s interned. You need to search a set of all previously constructed `String`s. Note this must be done in a thread-safe manner, which adds overhead. Because you don't want this to leak, you need to be using some form of (thread-safe) non-strong references.

Of course, you can't implement Java like this because the library unfortunately exposes constructors for `String`s and most other immutable value objects.

Answer (score 1):

The new keyword always makes a new string.

[More detail here](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3).

Answer (score 1):

> Why don't all the strings have the same location in memory if all three have the same contents?

Because they are **different** strings with same content!

Comment: String s1 = "BloodParrot is the man";
String s2 = "BloodParrot is the man";

s1 == s2 => true
It seems that s1 and s2 are the SAME strings.

Comment: Those two *are* identical, pointing to the same address. Only s3 is different, because it is explicitly created as a new string.

Comment: There is no guarantee that s1 and s2 will be the same object.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method called String.intern which, essentially, takes all Strings that are the same and puts them into a hash table (I am sort of lying, but for this it is the concept that matters, not the reality).

```
String s1 = "BloodParrot is the man";  
String s2 = "BloodParrot is the man";  
String s3 = new String("BloodParrot is the man").intern();  

System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
System.out.println(s1 == s2);
System.out.println(s1 == s3);
System.out.println(s1.equals(s3));
```

should have them all being "true".  This is because (and I am lying a bit here again, but it still only matters for the concept not reality)  String s1 = "BloodParrot is the man"; is done something like String s1 = "BloodParrot is the man".intern();