# Comparing two strings in android

Tags: android, json, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing two identical strings with == returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7375427/comparing-two-identical-strings-with-returns-false)

I am having real hard time with solving this code. This might look silly but I am not able to figure out what is happening. I am parsing a `JSONArray`(No big deal!) I am traversing the array with a for loop. I want to break the loop when the user input and the value matches. Here is my code

```
String regi = null;
JSONObject studentObject = null;
try {
JSONArray returned = test.getInternetData();
int i;
for (i = 0; i < returned.length(); i++) {
    studentObject = returned.getJSONObject(i);
    regi = studentObject.getString("REGISTRATION_NO");
    if (regi == reg) {
        name = studentObject.getString("STUDENT_NAME");
        break;
    }
}
course = studentObject.getString("COURSE_CODE");
Log.d("Details", name + course + regi + i);//Out put: nullGraduate081018394:name - null
//course: Graduate (same for all), regi: last registration number, 
//i: giving totalnumber of objects
```

As per my knowledge the loop should stop when it finds a match. The `COURSE_CODE` will be corresponding to the student. Am I missing something?

**Please note:** The function `getInternetData()` is returning the whole `JSON Array`. The loop is completely traversing every object.

Comment: I am not sure which line is causing trouble. I think my case is bit different

Comment: what is name here that you are printing in log? It doesnt have any data (it is a null variable as from the post you did)

Comment: @Sharath I am sure I am not comparing null variables. Which varible is null can you please point out?

Comment: its not comparing but just try changing this line Log.d("Details", name + course + regi + i) to Log.d("Details", name + " - "+course +" - "+ regi  +" - "+ i) and be back with the output you are getting in log

Comment: Doesn't change much. I am getting something like this:

`null`-`Graduate`-`081018394`-`18`. Where as I should get my name in place of null, my registration number and my slno. I am getting all details form last object and name turns to be null.

Comment: and even change if (regi == reg) {
        name = studentObject.getString("STUDENT_NAME");
        break;
    } to any of the suggested ones below. The one you wrote just compares memory locations as far as i know and not the content

Comment: So sorry server was not responding. After changing the `==` it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings cannot be compared with `==` in Java. You have to use `string1.equals(string2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `regi.equals(reg)` or `regi.contentEquals(reg)` instead of `==` and you will be fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

use  `regi.contentEquals(reg)`  or `!regi.contentEquals(reg)`  for comparison

Answer (score 1):

you should use `regi.contentEquals(reg)`

Comment: String hi = "hi";
String hello = "hi";
if(hi==hello){
//do something
}
This works.

Comment: And this tends to not: `char c = 'i'; String a = "hi"; String b = "h" + c; if (a == b) { //something }`. `==` does an object comparison, whereas `equals()` does a `String` comparison. Read through the actual answer I linked.

Comment: OK then try the sysout way... System.out.println("regi: -" + regi + "-  reg: -" + reg + "-");  and see if you can spot any weird thing :)

Comment: @DibyaPanda: Java interns String literals. So when you create to String literals `String a = "..."; String b = "..."`, it first adds the String "..." to a table of interned Strings, then when you create the second String b, it looks up "...", sees it in the table of intered Strings, and b will point to the same String a does. However, when you are not literally declaring Strings, this will not always work. == checks to see if two primitives have same value or if two objects point to the same underlying object.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
JSONArray returned = test.getInternetData();
int i;
for (i = 0; i < returned.length(); i++) {
// added the below line
studentObject = new JsonObject();
studentObject = returned.getJSONObject(i);
regi = studentObject.getString("REGISTRATION_NO");
if (regi.equals(reg)) {
    name = studentObject.getString("STUDENT_NAME");
    break;
}
}
```

instead of just

```
JSONArray returned = test.getInternetData();
int i;
for (i = 0; i < returned.length(); i++) {
studentObject = returned.getJSONObject(i);
regi = studentObject.getString("REGISTRATION_NO");
if (regi == reg) {
    name = studentObject.getString("STUDENT_NAME");
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: I think you were right using `==` causes problem. I think the code your code should be updated.

Comment: yes yes sorry for the mistake