# Why two strings with the same name have the same object instance?

Tags: java, instance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String equality vs equality of location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594604/string-equality-vs-equality-of-location)

This my first question, be patient with me, please

I have the following code:

```
String str1 = "hello";
String str2 = "hello";
System.out.println(str1 == str2);
```

And the result is **true**

Why?

Comment: String literal interning.

Comment: Is your question "why does this work when other comparisons do not?" or "why is the language defined this way?"

Comment: Both questions are very interesting, could you explain them? But my question was the first one

Comment: read the link provided by @Evan Mulawski

Comment: Analogical example, if you are interested. You have 4 variables: `Integer a = 120;
Integer b = 120;
Integer c = 130;
Integer d = 130;`
You will never quess what will print next line:
`System.out.println((a == b) + " and " + (c == d));`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Java finds same literals during compile time it creates a single instance of it and refers that to all the references.

str1 and str2 both have same literals "hello" so jvm creates a single instance of it and assigns it to str1 and str2.

So when you do str1==str2 you get true. (Both are referencing to the same instance)

Answer (score -4):

Because == means equal to so you are saying str1 and str2 equal each other.. AND that is true yes

Comment: This is not necessarily true.

Comment: @Hassan Leave out "necessarily" :) This is **never** true. There is **never** a comparison by string value done.

Comment: Agreed, `==` returns `true` when twp *primitives* are equal, or when two objects point to the same location in memory (which is what primitives do anyways). Strings, when defined like they are by the OP, are internally routed to the same location in memory, so they are equal.

Comment: @Jon Just to make it perfectly clear, it's not the strings that are equal, but the reference vars themselves.